# Looking for a way to encode and decode h.264 video on a frame by frame basis

Tags: video, encoding, h.264

The problem I am trying to solve involves sending video over the network using a custom transport. That is to say, I need compressed video but the actual transmission is not a standard protocol, however, I still need to packetize the frames. What I am looking for is a way to pass individual frame grabs of an input source into an encoder, transmit the encoded output across the network, and then decode the frame into some image (standard bitmap preferred) on the other end. It is required that I use h.264, but a particular language is not required. My platform is Linux.

I looked into ffmpeg and vlc but the only encoding and decoding functions I see are for entire files. I, unfortunately, do not have the entire file available to me at the time of encoding. i just have single images coming in one at a time.

Something like this:

```
byte[] inputFrame = someImage;
byte[] encodedFrame = H264Encoder.EncodeNextFrame(inputFrame);
...Transmit frame
byte[] inputFrame = H264Decoder.DecodeNextFrame(encodedFrame);
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you finally able to solve that above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend libavformat/libavcodec. These are the libraries behind ffmpeg. A good starting point can be found here http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/. Its a little out of date, and you will need to look  at the documentation to find the updated calling conventions. For example av_open_input_file() is now avformat_open_input().

Answer (score 1):

I would write my own ffmpeg muxer/demuxer for your proprietary protocol/format or at least use its rtp packetization for h.264 bitstream.

It's not so scary as it sounds:

- populate AVOutputFormat/AVInputFormat structures with some general info (name, supported extensions), pointers to functions write_header, write_packet, write_trailer (and read_header, read_packet, read_close),
- call av_register_output_format/av_register_input_format for those structs,
- use them in your encoding/decoding process.

> What I am looking for is a way to pass individual frame grabs

Maybe it's overkill to use h.264 for individual frames encoding. H.264 is designed for encoding groups of pictures, because all those features as I/P/B-frames, multiple reference frames, motion estimation don't make sense if you encode just one frame. Actually the resulting stream will contain I-frames only, so I would consider simple jpeg encoding for resolving your problem.

Comment: H.264 Intra-only outperforms JPEG in almost all circumstances for a given bitrate.
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4433263
https://www.scribd.com/document/2581731/H-264-AVC-intra-coding-and-JPEG-2000-comparison
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6411873
However single image encoding is usually easier to implement.